# Analyzing an Inequality

Tags: analysis

I'm considering the following estimate in something that I'm reading:

Consider $z \in B(0,R)$ and the following expression:
$$\int_{|y|<2R}u(y)e^{-|z-y|^2/2t}dy + \int_{|y|\geq2R}u(y)e^{-|z-y|^2/2t}dy$$

The text wishes to come up with an estimate for the exponents. So it writes:

> If $|y| \geq 2$ we get $|z-y|^2 \geq (|y|-|z|)^2 \geq |y|^2/4$

The first inequality is reverse triangle ineqality. I'm lost at how the next inequality comes about. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming it's for the second term *(are you missing a "$R$" in the "If $\lvert y\rvert \geq 2$"?)*. In that one, we have $\lvert y \rvert \geq 2R$; since $\lvert z\rvert < R$ (as $z\in B(0,r)$), we get
$$
\lvert y\rvert-\lvert z\rvert \geq \frac{\lvert y\rvert}{2}
$$
and squaring gives what you want.

Comment: there's no "$R$" - I guess there's a typo in what I'm reading then.

Comment: @yoshi Unless $R$ is known to be less than 1, yes.

Comment: well..$R$ comes from $B(0,R)$. This is part of a continuity argument - so $R$ can be made arbitrarily small. Does this change the inequality then?

Comment: No, it R is less than 1 then y greater than 2 implies y greater than 2R. But it would be clearer with a R in the inequality to begin with, so I still assume it's a typo.